# .NET 4.0 Web Forms Routing w/ Multiple Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, webforms, url-rewriting

I am not super experienced with Routing, so if I am not using this correctly, please let me know.

I have 3 routes created: LocationPages, ServicePages and StaticPages. I have these broke into 3 routes because they are stored in 3 tables in the db. My problem is that the content for the default.aspx page for both LocationPages and ServicePages is stored in the StaticPages table as it doesn't have the same structure of the actual location or service page.

My problem is that when going to domain.com/locations/, the LocationPages route picks it up when the StaticPages route should and same thing for the serivce pages. It picks it up because the route for location pages is domain.com/locations/cityname/.

I tried to use Response.RedirectToRoute("StaticPages") in the event it can't find the location page so the static page routing can handle it and query up the location's default page or send to a 404. However, everytime the route param is null.

Here is my code & routes:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapPageRoute("LocationPages", "Locations/{*RouteLocation}", "~/LocationRouteHandler.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("ServicePages", "Services/{*RouteService}", "~/ServiceRouteHandler.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("StaticPages", "{*RoutePage}", "~/default.aspx");

}
```

Location Route Handler:

```
protected void GetLocationPage()
{
    try
    {
        string RouteLocation = Page.RouteData.Values["RouteLocation"] as string;

        if (RouteLocation.EndsWith("/"))
            RouteLocation = RouteLocation.TrimEnd('/');

        AccessLocation location = new AccessLocation();
        lpd = location.GetLocationDetailByRouteLocation(RouteLocation);

        if (lpd != null)
        {
            if (lpd.LocationPage.Active == false)
                Response.Redirect("~/Error/404.aspx");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/404.aspx");
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.RedirectToRoute("StaticPages");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Static Page Route Handler:

```
protected void GetContentPage()
{
    try
    {
        string RoutePage = Page.RouteData.Values["RoutePage"] as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RoutePage))
            RoutePage = "Home";

        if (RoutePage.EndsWith("/"))
            RoutePage = RoutePage.TrimEnd('/');

        AccessContent content = new AccessContent();
        cpd = content.GetContentDetailByRoutePage(RoutePage);

        if (cpd != null)
        {
            if (cpd.ContentPage.Active == false)
                Response.Redirect("~/Error/404.aspx");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/404.aspx");
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Error/404.aspx");
    }
}
```

When I debug, I do see it goes into the method of the static page, but the RoutePage variable is always null.

Thanks for all help!